# Calling component from one js file to another js file

Tags: extjs

I have a grid panel in Printers.ascx page.Is there any way i can  call this grid panel from Filetrs.ascx page

Ext.getCmp('gridpanel') can be done if it is in the same page but how can we call accross pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since .ascx files are server controls, they can be embedded in the same .aspx page.  Any Ext (or JS code in general) can call any other functions on the page as long as they are both loaded and you have access to the proper scope (including code loaded in different ascx files).  If you really do mean separate aspx pages, then no, you cannot call across pages directly from JS code.  You'd have to make a server call, or perhaps save state via a state mechanism like cookies for instance and have each component access the same data.  It really depends on what you are trying to do.